# Cannot fit two Jumbotrons Horizontally (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap and I am having some trouble getting two jumbotrons to sit on one row (without space in between.) No matter how small I make their respective columns, they stay on separate rows.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
            <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Title</h1>
            <p class="lead">Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
            <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Active</h1>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have not messed with the default bootstrap CSS. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class of the containing div should to be `row`, not `col`:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's Grid system has column spacing (padding) by default. There are a few ways to address this issue to adapt to your requirements.

One approach could be to add a new CSS selector, and then modify your HTML accordingly.

CSS:

```
/* Add this */
.no-padding {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="col-md-6 no-padding"> <!-- add no-padding -->
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
            <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Title</h1>
            <p class="lead">Description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 no-padding"> <!-- add no-padding -->
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
            <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Active</h1>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing to row instead of col as suggested below worked (which I tried first because this is a small project and I do not have a css file linked) but thank you for your answer as well! It looks like either could have done it.